# Include List of Tables directly in each section/subsection etc. in Table of Contents

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I'd like to include my list of tables directly in the ToC. This means tables of every section, subsection etc. are listed in the ToC and not in the list of tables separately.

This example below does not result in what I want. `Table 1` should follow directly under `subtitle1`, `Table 2` under `subtitle2`, and `Table 3` just below `title2`...

How do I have to modify his example?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{title1}
\subsection{subtitle1}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 1}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{subtitle2}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 2}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{title2}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 3}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
% tablesintocprob.tex SE 554629

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
%\listoftables

\newpage
\section{title1}
\subsection{subtitle1}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Table 1}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{subtitle2}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Table 2}
\label{tab:my-other-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{title2}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Table 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Table 3}
\label{tab:my-another-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
neo & old
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure that it gives the result you are after but it will give you a start.